# How do I use Google Apps Script via Python?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

So I have used the script editor from https://script.google.com/home to make many programs that help me with my (non-programming) job.

I've recently been learning about data visualization libraries in Python, and I feel it would be awesome if I could use Python in my Google scripts so that I can attach Python-created pictures onto my gmail/forms/docs I create.

When I look at the documentation for the different Google services, I see Python mentioned. But I have no idea how to use it to work with Google Apps Script, or if it's even possible. I couldn't find a good Youtube video that explains it. I don't know, maybe I just don't know the vocabulary (I'm a self-taught programmer).

Exactly what steps do I have to take to start using Google Apps Script via Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't use Google apps script **directly** with python(There however is a [beta program](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes-overview)).

The straightforward way to use python with Google apps is to skip apps script and use the respective apis directly, if one is available. Most popular Google apps do have a external api. Eg: [Docs-Api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python), [Gmail-api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python).

Alternatively, You can  manipulate apps script through [apps script api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api). Here you'll be able to modify apps script and run apps script through python, but the executing code on the server is still apps script. You may also be able to create a [apps script webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and make it a custom api accepting `GET`/`POST` requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Hmm, so one great thing about Google Apps Script is my ability to use triggers that allow me to automate certain functions. Would the same level of automation be possible via the apps script API? Like, can I set up Google Apps Script triggers to automatically run the python code?

(Sorry if I sound naive. I have an idea of what APIs are used for, but never actually used them).

Comment: @BaronMcDonald If you run apps script and set up a trigger, why do you need python? Python runs locally on your device/terminal. `Cronjob` might help, but you need your device to be on. Python also runs in cloud like Google cloud functions or on Google app engine, which does offer some triggers, but they are at least partly paid solutions.

Comment: So to be specific: I have a program that automatically emails students their classwork grades. I want to use Python to create images of this data, and then use Google apps script to attach those photos to the emails

Comment: @BaronMcDonald Your best bet is Google cloud functions or Google app engine running Python. Http Post from apps script and get image data from  Python(running on cloud functions)